# Hazelcast LifecycleListener stateChanged never firing

Tags: event-handling, hazelcast, lifecycle

I would like to keep track of the Hazelcast lifecycle. The default logging comes up with events lke

`INFO: [192.168.201.11]:5701 [MyApp] [4.1.2] [192.168.201.11]:5701 is STARTING`

`INFO: [192.168.201.11]:5701 [MyApp] [4.1.2] [192.168.201.11]:5701 is STARTED`

so I'd l like these events telling me the status is STARTING or STARTED, etc.

Here's how I'm starting up

```
var hzConfig = new Config();
hzConfig.setClusterName(clusterName);
hzConfig.setInstanceName(memberId);
instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hzConfig)
var lifecycleListener = new LifecycleListener();
lifecycleListenerId = instance.getLifecycleService().addLifecycleListener(lifecycleListener);
```

And here's my LifecycleListener

```
public class LifecycleListener implements com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleListener {

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(LifecycleEvent lifecycleEvent) {
        System.out.println("Lifecycle change: " + lifecycleEvent.getState());
    }
}
```

All very basic, but my LifeCycleListener doesn't get any events, neither on starting up, nor on shutting down.

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote is correct. The reason why you don't see the logs is that your Hazelcast instance starts before your LifecycleListener is added.

Try the following code.

```
var hzConfig = new Config();
hzConfig.setClusterName(clusterName);
hzConfig.setInstanceName(memberId);
instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hzConfig)
var lifecycleListener = new LifecycleListener();
lifecycleListenerId = instance.getLifecycleService().addLifecycleListener(lifecycleListener);

Thread.sleep(5000);
instance.shutdown();
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

You should see the following log.

```
Lifecycle change: SHUTTING_DOWN
...
Lifecycle change: SHUTDOWN
```

Comment: Somehow I came to a similar conclusion. When I fired up my second instance, the first instance would register some lifetime events even on the first instance.
Can I assume that once I have the ´instance´ that the status is automatically STARTED?